# How to cancel Socket.ReceiveFromAsync()?

Tags: c#, .net-core, udp

I'm working with dotnet core 2.2 and have the following UDP listener:

```
var socket = new Socket(ep.AddressFamily, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
while (true)
{
    var result = await socket.ReceiveFromAsync(...);
}
```

Now in certain scenarios I would like to interrupt the `ReceiveFromAsync()` call. But it seems that unlike TCP case (i.e. `ReceiveAsync()`) there is no `ReceiveFromAsync()` overload accepting `CancellationToken`.

One option would be to use `Task.Delay(-1, ct);` together with `Task.WhenAny()/Task.WhenAll()`. But I think that this solution leads to memory leak, right? I mean the `.ReceiveFromAsync()` call still "exists" if interrupted, just in background. Also may lead to broken logic because such call will read an UDP packet and discard it afterwards? Or is my reasoning incorrect?

Another idea would be to have a background worker that reads from the UDP socket and queues each packet. And no interruption can happen here. Then I would read from the queue and interrupt this call. That would work but definitely requires some effort. The issues I see is: thread safety and performance.

Is there a cleaner/simplier way to handle this situation?

Comment: Why do you want to interrupt the UDP receive?

Comment: @StephenCleary there is a scenario when some "admin" connects to the server and says "pls stop listening now, maintanance upcoming". The thing is that this can be a very short maintanance, like few hundred millis at most. So if possible without killing the process, just interrupt for a short duration. Just "suspended" state in order to precisely calculate current metrics. The idea might be broken to begin with, but is that really relevant? Let's assume that the "why" question is irrelevant. For academic purposes. :)

Comment: I would just close the socket, then.

Comment: @StephenCleary Hmm, I suppose that's an option. Do you think that's the best solution? If so, pls post it as an answer. Although to be honest: `ReceiveFromAsync` should accept a `CancellationToken` to begin with. Also: could you address my concerns about `Task.Delay` pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For "uncancelable" I/O requests, the standard pattern in Windows is to close the underlying handle - in this case, the socket. This generally causes any asynchronous (or synchronous, for that matter) operations to complete with an error code.

In your situation - "pausing" a UDP receiver - I think this approach especially makes sense. UDP sockets do not represent open connections anyway, so closing the socket is the best solution.

Regarding `Task.Delay` with `Task.WhenAny`, your concerns are perfectly valid. The `Task.Delay` + `Task.WhenAny` approach only cancels the *wait* of the operation, not the operation itself. Specifically, it would not cancel the UDP receive, and that uncanceled UDP receive operation may get a packet that would then be "lost", since your app would ignore it.